# How to repeat a filter function multiple times (per dynamic column range)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table `A1:C8`.

`G1` and `H1` contain a range begin and end.

This is used to create a sequence of columns for the range (starting in K1 with function: `=SEQUENCE(1;(H1-G1)+1;G1;1)`)

[image]

Now `K2` has a `FILTER` function which filters the value(s) by the given column value `K1`. (real life data is more complex)

[image]

The question is simple, maybe the solution not:

**How do a repeat that filter function for the given (dynamic sequence)?**

`K2` would be: `=FILTER(A2:A8; B2:B8 >= K1; "nothing")`

`L2` would be: `=FILTER(A2:A8; B2:B8 >= L1; "nothing")`

`M2` would be: `=FILTER(A2:A8; B2:B8 >= M1; "nothing")`

...

repating for the given dynamic column range defined by this sequence: `=SEQUENCE(1;(H1-G1)+1;G1;1)`.

Comment: `=FILTER(A2:A8; B2:B8 >= INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, COLUMN())); "nothing")`?

Comment: The SEQUENCE must have a range, right? Otherwise it can be slow.

Comment: @rint the sequence range is defined by G1 and H1 (start G1 and length is (H1-G1)+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve the desired output using `LAMBDA()` helper function called `MAKEARRAY()` --> Will expand any number of rows/columns without doing it recursively and without the help of stacking after each iterations. Will be comparatively quicker and efficient than any `LAMBDA()` helper functions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:C8,
     _Rows, MAX(COUNTIFS(TAKE(_Data,,2),">="&K1#)),
     _Columns, COLUMNS(K1#),
     IFERROR(MAKEARRAY(_Rows, _Columns, LAMBDA(r,c,
     INDEX(FILTER(TAKE(_Data,,1),INDEX(_Data,,2)>=INDEX(K1#,c),"nothing"),r))),""))
```

---

Comment: can't get this to work:
"The first argument of LET must be a valid name."

Comment: @juFo you need to change the separators, see I am using `comma` `,` you need to use `semicolon` `;` its based on `locale settings`. Change all those commas to semicolon and then use the formula it will certainly work as shown already in the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

With `REDUCE` function you can use:

```
=IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",K1#,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,FILTER(A2:A8,B2:B8>=b,"nothing")))),,1),"")
```

Data as given by OP.
[image: Dynamic list]

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: This gives that it is not a valid formula

Comment: It requires a new version of Excel (Microsoft 365). Which version do you use? Or maybe you need semicolons as separators (instead of commas).